# is search a true mode in vim?

Tags: search

Listed [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Learning_the_vi_Editor/Vim/Modes) is "each mode" for vim.

I did not see "search" in the list, but I should think that search (`/` or `?`) would be a mode on its own.

I have to make a very formal presentation about my internship, and I had some space on my poster, so I decided to put a small section regarding how important text editors are for coders since they are in them so much. Since I learned a lot, as I would look up things at home and occasionally at work regarding how to do something, I decided to put a little about vim. So, this seemingly trivial question is actually fairly important to me currently ... and I wouldn't wan to to mislead anyone :P (despite the fact that no one will care and it is, indeed, extremely trivial).

---

ps I didn't notice a "search-mode" tag for stackexchange tags below. Does that mean that I have already guess the answer?

... What do you all think? Is search a "true" mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These few commands that are only available while searching via `/` / `?` with `'incsearch'`: `<c-l>`, `<c-g>`, and `<c-t>`.

I am not sure 3 commands constitute a mode, but maybe it does. If we look at the documentation it is listed as a command mode mapping and there is no special `map` variant to make more such mappings, e.g. `nmap` for normal or `xmap` for visual. So it maybe more of a battle of semantics.

Note: there maybe more search only mappings/commands, but I can not think of any.

See the following for more help:

```
:h /_CTRL-L
:h /_CTRL-G
:h /_CTRL-T
```

Comment: OK! **(1)** » I was not aware of these search-... eh whatever mappings! Thank you so very much! **(2)** » Maybe I just feel like since I am using search a lot, it feels like a mode. I still find myself grasping for straws regarding if this should be considered a mode or not. I suppose it doesn't really matter, but thanks for your input! … AND for your awesome tips!

Comment: btw! Presentation was a big hit — although vim was not the center of attention :P

Comment: @dylnmc: I am glad. If want and are able you may want to post your presentation on vim's subreddit, [r/vim](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/). It would be neat to have more resources to point newer vimmer towards.

Answer (score 1):

`help: search-commands` returns the stuff I type to execute searches.

Since these are all commands, I always thought of `/`  and `?` as commands, used in command mode.

Comment: OK! Thanks for your two cents! I suppose I won't use it as a mode of its own. It would take up more space than it's worth anyway! Cheers, dylnmc